# Looking for replacement part for under-drawer catch

Tags: drawers

I have a drawer which uses the following catch mounted under it. The problem is that the straight vertical-ish segment doesn't extend enough to the right to be able to click firmly into the runner.
[image: Picture of under-drawer catch]

For now, I have hacked it by inserting a small flexible eraser that puts sufficient force to hold it against the rail:
[image: Picture of temporary hack]

Can someone help me identify where I can find a replacement part for this? I googled for 710.611 and some references to "Salice" showed up, but no exact matches for the part number. Does anyone know if 710.610 would work instead? (e.g. https://www.wwhardware.com/salice-front-fixing-clips-left-right-futura)

Comment: aren't the 610 and 611 the same thing in left and right versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Ways to adjust this.]

Unscrew, plug holes with toothpicks and glue, trim right end of the part near the top of the picture, reinstall shoved further right, drill new screw holes.

<s>*If the white lever that moves the gray cam provides enough range of motion, you could possibly move it far enough over not to have to plug the screw holes, but that seems dubious. Ideally set that to the middle of its range when determining how much to trim.*</s>

Or, loosen both screws, shim between the left end the drawer where it screws in, and tighten both screws.

Comment: Ha, I'm kicking myself for not thinking of the shim approach :) should work well enough. And you're right, the white lever only adjusts drawer vertical leveling/alignment.